# Forcing HTML textarea to use a monospace font using CSS

Tags: html, css

How can I make my text area use a monospaced font?

Answer (score 114, accepted):

If I'm understanding properly, it should already inherit default user-agent styles, but if you want to explicitly, just specify a font-family ( styles jacked from Stackoverflow stylesheet )

```
textarea {
  font-family:Consolas,Monaco,Lucida Console,Liberation Mono,DejaVu Sans Mono,Bitstream Vera Sans Mono,Courier New, monospace;
}
```

Specify the more specific (monospace-specific) font families first, and if the user agent doesn't have that available it will keep trying them until the end, in which case it would default to the default user agent font family for that element, if any was specified.

Comment: You might want to add a `monospace` to the end of that, to get the default fallback monospace font if none of the other ones specified exist.

Comment: ah missed that; my eye tricked me and I thought it was there.

Comment: Ahhh. I had font-family: "monospace"; I bet it's the quotes which are messing it up.

Comment: Hey, don't forget my favorite, Menlo.

Comment: remove the border part in your css, it is not part of the question and confuses unconfident followers

Answer (score 27):

You can also use the standard generic `font-family: monospace`, but be careful -- there are some *severe* side effects (sadly) in Chrome, Safari and anything WebKit based.

see:

- http://webkit.org/blog/67/strange-medium/
- http://archivist.incutio.com/viewlist/css-discuss/103606

Comment: +1 for the warnings about inconsistent browser defaults; luckily this application is for programmers exclusive (in our company) who can be expected to set their browser fonts according to their desires.

Comment: To avoid most of the problems with browsers doing inexplicable things, you can use `font-family: monospace,monospace;`.

Comment: Broken link: http://archivist.incutio.com/viewlist/css-discuss/103606

Answer (score 17):

Just use a monospace font. For example for something like:

```
<textarea id="mytextarea"></textarea>
```

the css would be:

```
#mytextarea {
    font-family: monospace;
}
```

If you want to use a specific monospace font, you can but don't forget adding the generic 'monospace' at the end in case the user does not have your preferred font installed:

```
#mytextarea {
    font-family: 'DejaVu Sans Mono', monospace;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
textarea
{
font-family: monospace;
}
```

You may need to add an important if not working

```
textarea
{
font-family: monospace !important;
}
```