# What code do I need to make the number of columns of this textbox equal to the number of characters?

Tags: html, text

I have the number of columns set to 40 but the textbox can fit 41 characters. I need the number of characters to be exactly the number of columns since I have a function that counts the number of lines of text based on the number of columns.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>


<style type="text/css">

textarea
{
    border: 0 none white;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    outline: none;
    background-color: #D0D0D0;
    resize: none;
}
</style>

<script>

function countLines(theArea)
{
  var theLines = theArea.value.replace((new RegExp(".{"+theArea.cols+"}","g")),"\n").split("\n");

  if(theLines[theLines.length-1]=="")
  theLines.length--;
  theArea.form.lineCount.value = theLines.length;
}
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
var observe;
if (window.attachEvent) 
{
    observe = function (element, event, handler) 
    {
        element.attachEvent('on'+event, handler);
    };
}
else 
{
    observe = function (element, event, handler)
    {
        element.addEventListener(event, handler, false);
    };
}
function init ()
{
    var text = document.getElementById('text');
    function resize () 
    {
        text.style.height = 'auto';
        text.style.height = text.scrollHeight+'px';
    }
    /* 0-timeout to get the already changed text */
    function delayedResize ()
    {
        window.setTimeout(resize, 0);
    }
    observe(text, 'change',  resize);
    observe(text, 'cut',     delayedResize);
    observe(text, 'paste',   delayedResize);
    observe(text, 'drop',    delayedResize);
    observe(text, 'keydown', delayedResize);

    text.focus();
    text.select();
    resize();
}


</script>

</head>

<body onload="init();">
<form>


<textarea rows="5" cols="40" style="height:1em;" id="text"; name="myText" onKeyUp="countLines(this)">

</textarea>


<br>
Cost: <input type=text name="lineCount" size="1" value="0"> Dollars

</form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: The `cols` attribute is based on "average character width".  So, depending on the font, the actual number of characters may vary.  Try setting the textarea to use a monospaced font: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2032652

Answer (score 1):

`cols` is defined as average character width.  Depending on your font and which letters you are using, you may be able to fit more or less characters per line.  Using a fixed-width font, such as Courier may help this, but I wouldn't depend on `cols` to restrict your user to a certain line length.  `cols` only forces word-wrapping at some approximate `textarea` width.  I would not depend on it to restrict line length.

If you are already using JavaScript, why not have a key handler that uses a RegEx to insert newline characters after every 40 characters?

**Edit:**

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jtbowden/qkhRh/

Demo with separate formatted output: http://jsfiddle.net/jtbowden/cX8yE/

Comment: If I don't use a monospace font, how would I go about counting the number of lines? The 40 cols is arbitrary, but I actually want the width of the box to be set at exactly 265 pixels because that is the width of the column in my newspaper. So I want clients to be able to paste their article into the textbox and have it output the number of lines that their article will take up given the set width of the column and font size of 7.

Comment: I would suggest doing the output in a seperate text box, but you could do it in the same, as in this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jtbowden/qkhRh/

Comment: ok so that fixed the problem with the line count, but now it runs into the problem where i can't hit "enter" and type more text on the next line. i can only get to the next line if it reaches the end and overflows to the next line.

Comment: also, if i paste a large block of text it will automatically reformat the text and delete the spaces. in the original function it would keep the format as is.

Comment: These are just examples.  You will need more code to fulfill all of your requirements.  And I don't know all of your requirements.  Here is a much more complicated example that retains the original text, doesn't break words unless they are >40 characters and accepts copy-paste: http://jsfiddle.net/jtbowden/mv7UP/

Comment: well ideally i want something like this: http://i.imgur.com/avHqRWb.png

i think it would be easier for the user to actually output the text in the same box rather than a separate box don't you think? that way they can go in and edit what they write.

Comment: You have some conflicting requirements.  You are inserting newlines, but want to retain the user's newlines.  This makes it more difficult.  If you change the final line of the function to `textin` instead of `textout`, you get most of what you want, but when a user goes back and edits, you may get some undesirable behavior.