# Add spaces to javascript string depending on element width

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a form to add users to a select list from 2 textboxes (Last name and First name).

When I click on the "+" button, it adds an option with the last name and first name specified to the select element below. Right now, it adds the option with only one white space between last and first name, but I would like the first name to be aligned with the above "First name" textbox.

Here's a fiddle with my sample code: http://jsfiddle.net/fx37j71s/12/

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>Last Name</td>
    <td>First Name</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><input type="text" id="txtlastname" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="txtfirstname" /></td>
    <td><input type="button" value="+" onclick="addemployee();" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="2"><select id="lbxname" size="5" style="width:500px"></select></td>
    <td valign="top"><input type="button" value="-"onclick="removeemployee();" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

And the addemployee() function:

```
function addemployee()
{
    var lastname = document.getElementById('txtlastname');
    var firstname = document.getElementById('txtfirstname');
    var select = document.getElementById('lbxname');
    var option = document.createElement('option');
    var text = document.createTextNode(lastname.value + ' ' + firstname.value);

    option.appendChild(text);
    select.appendChild(option);
}
```

Is there a way to achieve this in JS or jquery or maybe CSS? I have tried to add a fixed amount of spaces minus the amount of characters in Last name, but the actual width of the string depends on the characters (i.e. "PPPPP" is wider than "lllll" even though they both have 5 characters). I also found the "clientWidth" property, but I can't seem to make it work properly.

Thank you :)

Comment: Can you just set the textarea to use a monospaced font? Then your method would likely work. Edit: [here's how](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2032652/how-do-i-get-an-html-text-area-with-monospaced-text-using-css).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on charlietfl's answer and Evilzebra's comment, this worked for me:

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vcfpd450/2/

```
function addemployee()
{
    var lastname = document.getElementById('txtlastname');
    var firstname = document.getElementById('txtfirstname');
    var select = document.getElementById('lbxname');
    var option = document.createElement('option');   


    option.innerHTML=padStr(lastname.value) +  firstname.value;   
    select.appendChild(option);
}


function padStr(str){
    var x = str.length;
    while(x < 31){
        str+='&nbsp';
        ++x;
    }    
    return str;
}
```

CSS:

```
#lbxname
{
    font-family: monospace;
}
```

Basically, I add spaces to the string until I reach the desired width (31 in this case). Using a monospace font-family makes sure the width is consistent with the number of characters.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of creating textNode can set `innerHTML`

Something like:

```
function addemployee()
{
    var lastname = document.getElementById('txtlastname');
    var firstname = document.getElementById('txtfirstname');
    var select = document.getElementById('lbxname');
    var option = document.createElement('option');   


    option.innerHTML = padStr(lastname.value) +  firstname.value;   
    select.appendChild(option);
}


function padStr(str){
    while(str.length < 500){
        str += '&nbsp;';
    }    
    return str
}
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vcfpd450/)**</kbd>

Comment: I rejected [Jonathan's attempted edit](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/6048502) as an attempt to reply. He did, though, provide the following updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vcfpd450/2/

Comment: @JonathanParent In situations like these, please add a comment to the answer, indicating what you think might need to be changed. Editing is for revising/improving, and isn't intended to significantly *change* the intent of the answer.

Comment: @JonathanParent your edits really should have been posted as comments

Comment: @admdrew Alright, I am new to posting on stackoverflow, thanks for pointing it out to me.