# Make a textarea where the width of each character is always the same

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML code to make a `textarea` (it uses a class of Microsoft UI Fabric, but it is not very important).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />
    <title>Title</title>  
    <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <link href="Office.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1.1/hosted/office.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link href="Common.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="Notification.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Home.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/fabric/1.0/fabric.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/fabric/1.0/fabric.components.min.css">
</head>
<body class="ms-font-m">
    <div id="content-main">
    <div class="padding">
    <div class="ms-TextField ms-TextField--multiline">
        <textarea class="ms-TextField-field" id="my" spellcheck=false style="font-size: 18px">
            ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP
            abcdefghijklmnop        
        </textarea>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is how the result looks like:

[image]

As we can see, unlike eg, the question editor of stackoverflow, the width of each character in my textarea is not the same. In normal html without `css`, does anyone know how to make a text area such that the width of each character inside is always the same? If I still want to use `css` of Microsoft UI Fabric, where should I do the modification?

Comment: I don't think it is possible without css. Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2032652/how-do-i-get-an-html-text-area-with-monospaced-text-using-css) question and answer to see how to do it with css.

Comment: In your case, you could add a inline style to the textarea to make it use a "monospace" font. Like this: `<textarea class="ms-TextField-field" id="my" spellcheck=false style="font-size: 18px;font-family:Consolas,Monaco,Lucida Console,Liberation Mono,DejaVu Sans Mono,Bitstream Vera Sans Mono,Courier New, monospace;">`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `fabric.components.css` has this:

```css
.ms-TextField.ms-TextField--multiline .ms-TextField-field {
  font-family: 'Segoe UI Regular WestEuropean', 'Segoe UI', 'Segoe WP', Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif;
}
```

So either modify your HTML classes to prevent that selector from selection your textarea, or set back the default `font-familiy: monospace` in a selector with more specificity.

```css
@import 'https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/fabric/1.0/fabric.min.css';
@import 'https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/fabric/1.0/fabric.components.min.css';
.ms-TextField.ms-TextField--multiline .ms-TextField-field {
  font-family: monospace;
}
```

```html
<div id="content-main">
  <div class="padding">
    <div class="ms-TextField ms-TextField--multiline">
      <textarea class="ms-TextField-field" id="my" spellcheck=false style="font-size: 18px">
        ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP
        abcdefghijklmnop        
      </textarea>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can replace the line:

```
<textarea class="ms-TextField-field" id="my" spellcheck=false style="font-size: 18px">
```

With

```
<textarea class="ms-TextField-field" id="my" spellcheck=false style="font-size: 18px; font-family: monospace;">
```

If you want to specify a specific monospace font, you can add it before the word `monospace`

```
<textarea class="ms-TextField-field" id="my" spellcheck=false style="font-size: 18px; font-family: 'DejaVu Sans Mono', monospace;">
```

Technically speaking, this is using *inline* css.

Answer (score 2):

(EDITED - had mixed up monospace and monotype)
just use a monospace font for that text field. In a monospace font all characters have the same width:

```
#my {
  font-family; monospace;
}
```